# burp i get not secure connection failed in firefox after the certificate imported and trusted

Tags: http, firefox, proxy, burp

i install burp and i install firefox configure everything right with burp certificate but the connection is still not secure.

i tried to see why with no success.

i use windows 10 burp and firefox last version

[image]

i tried to pause all my antivirus (eset and defender)

do you know what can i do?

do you know why this is happand?

Comment: Clear the Firefox cache to remove the saved HTTP Public Key Pinning (HPKP) entries (used by some web-sites). If it still does not work you have not correctly installed the Burp root-CA certificate.

Answer (score 0):

You may have imported the Burp CA certificate in the Your Certificates/People directory, as those will be the default option when importing the certificates. Ensure that it is installed under Authorities. And let us know if it still has the same error.